# Azure DevOps : not possible to publish again a deleted artifact

Tags: azure-devops, artifacts

I have a deleted artifact in a feed (and no more visible in the recycle bin, because permently deleted) :

[image: deleted artifact]

And I can't republish the same artifact, because It seems still present in the feed :

[image: artifact message]

[image]

I tried also to create a new feed :

[image: New empty feed]

And I tried to publish the same artifact in the new feed, but I have the following error message :

[image: New Feed]

[image: Upstreams(default)]

Could you tell me how can I republish the artifact please?

Regards,

Yannick

Answer (score 3):

> Azure DevOps : not possible to publish again a deleted artifact

This is the default behavior.

I understand how frustrating this is for you. But this is what Azure Artifacts deliberately designed to ensure the correctness of the build results.

Check the document: [Understand immutability of packages.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844661/overwrite-nuget-packages-in-feed-on-visual-studio-team-services/44877339#44877339)

> Once you publish a particular version of a package to a feed, that
> version number is permanently reserved. You cannot upload a newer
> revision package with that same version number, or delete it and
> upload a new package at the same version.

You could check [my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844661/overwrite-nuget-packages-in-feed-on-visual-studio-team-services/44877339#44877339) for the reason for this design.

To resolve this issue, you could try to publish the artifact with another version. If you do not want to change the version, you need to upload this artifact to another feed, and add this feed as package source.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. But the problem is that, the artifact deleted is the last version, and this version is required for our application. And your solution suggested about to publish the same artifact in an other feed doesn't work, because the feed is shared, and so Azure DevOps refuses to publish the same artifact in an other feed. So I'm really blocked. I saw in a documentation that the artifact is automatically deleted after 30 days, is it correct?

Comment: @yannick, You could publish the same artifact in an other feed, and feed is not shared. Let me know whay error you get when you publish to another feed, and the YAML and the type of the feed, project feed or org feed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I posted some screenshots (errors with the new feed) in my post above

Comment: I think I could maybe add a new upstream for repository.jboss.org-public. The JMS artifacts is available on this website. But when I try to add the upstream, it's recognized as a NPM type. What do you think?

Comment: @yannick, The custom upstream source only support npm at this moment. How about disable the Maven upstream source in your new feed?

Comment: @yannick, and the feed will cache the package from the upstream source, you do not need to push the package to the new feed, you could use new feed as package source with maven upstream source, that package will cache in the new feed.

Comment: Indeed, it's crazy. The using of these artifacts in DevOps is very complicated...